# Fetch lazy properties in Spring Projections

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently trying to evaluate the possibilies of using Spring Data JPA.

Trying to use Projections, I'm currently stuck in trying to fetch specific properties Eager.

I have a simple entity which lazy references another entity with a foreign key. I now would like to define different projections for the prior entity. "Primitive" properties are projected well into the projection interface, but trying to project another entity/projection results in it still being lazy loaded.

I would now like to tell Spring/JPA to eagerly load entities/projections inside projections. One possible way would be to use EntityGraphs (They were working well), but I would have to create repositories for each method using different graphs. Question being which other ways are there?

Example:

Entity Buyer:

```
@Entity
public class Buyer {
    private Integer id;
    private String someProperty;
    private User user;

    ...

    @OneToOne(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "CAB_USR_ID",
        referencedColumnName = "ID",
        updatable = false,
        nullable = true,
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_CAB_USR"))
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Entity User:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    ...

}
```

Projection Buyer

```
public interface BuyerCProjection {
    Integer getId();
    UserProjection getUser();
}
```

Projection User

```
public interface UserProjection {

    Integer getId();
    String getName();
}
```

Repository I would like to use

```
public interface BuyerRepository extends Repository<Buyer, Integer> {

    <T> List<T> findBy(Class<T> t);
}
```

Comment: [Closed Projection does not work with @EntityGraph](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1814)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to instruct JPA/Hibernate to fetch eagerly using projections. The projection is applied after the fetch query is executed, so it's too late to modify the query.

There's a compromise solution using the [jackson-datatype-hibernate](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate) module with the `FORCE_LAZY_LOADING` feature enabled. This forces all lazy-loaded objects in your projections to be initialized and returned.

Note that this isn't as efficient as writing custom queries using entity graphs or `JOIN FETCH`. It will behave the same as calling `Hibernate.initialize` on each lazy-loaded object, executing another select query. So it results in N+1 selects. But it can be a good way to get started. When something starts to be slow, you can still optimize by writing join-fetch or entity graph queries.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer, but, I hope it can help others.

The "@EntityGraph" annotation can provide user information to be loaded eagerly in your case.

Not tested, but I guess below repository method can work for your case. I am not sure about the implementation for your intended generic method implementation.

```
public interface BuyerRepository extends Repository<Buyer, Integer> {

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"user"})
    List<BuyerCProjection> findProjectedById(Integer id);
}
```

You can find a more detailed explanation on how to use Entity Graphs [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-named-entity-graphs)

Comment: Autor knows about the EntityGraph approach and asks if there is any other that would not force to create repositories for each method using different graphs.